# Rails Nested Forms - One to One with One to Many nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, nested-forms

I have a problem and I have a bit of a hard time explaining it. Here are my models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :publisher
  has_one :developer
end

class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :games
end

class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :games
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publisher
  belongs_to :developer
end
```

Basically a Company can be a Developer or Publisher or both. Then I can call `Company.publisher.games` to see all the games the company published, and `Company.developer.games` to see the games they developed.

The problem is I don't know the most efficient way to nest the forms for this.

Basically when I am at `/company/new`, I want to have a form for the company, which in turn has a box where I can specify multiple game IDs for either the Publisher or the Developer aspect of the company. I can't seem to figure out how I can just do `@company.update_attributes(params[:company])` and have that take a nested form and create a publisher and or developer with multiple associated games.